# Elasticsearch search against another field

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to match content against a list of words (for obscene word matching). As a simple example of what I need.

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      { "term": { "content": "word1" }},
      { "term": { "content": "word2" }}
           :
      { "term": { "content": "word1001" }}
    ]
  }
}
```

The words I am looking for 'word1', 'word1', ... 'word1001' are listed in another fields in another type.

What I need to achieve is something like

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      { "term": { "content": banned_words.word }},
    ]
  }
}
```

The words I need to match may number into the thousands, and the above boolean does not seem the most efficient. However, I cannot find an alternative to this.

Comment: I think you'd have to write a custom matcher for that. A vanilla boolean query for a 1000 elements is not going to be efficient anyway.

Comment: The initial request will be slow, however if you can use a filter instead of a query for your banned word-list, that filter will be cached (making subsequent executions extremely cheap!)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving this without matching all the bad words at query time is to match those words at indexing time using the [`synonym` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) and flag the documents containing bad words.

All you have to do is to store your bad words in a file on your file system (in Elasticsearch home directory):

`analysis/badwords.txt`:

```
word1 => BADWORD      <--- pick whatever you want the badword to be replaced with
word2 => BADWORD
...
word1000 => BADWORD
```

Then your index settings need to use that `synonym` token filter

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/my_index -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "badwords" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                    "filter" : ["synonym"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms_path" : "analysis/badwords.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "content": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "badwords"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Then when you index your documents with a `content` field containing some bad word matching the ones in your `badwords.txt` file, it will get properly replaced by the substitution word you chose in your synonyms file.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?analyzer=badwords&pretty' -d 'you are a word2'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "you",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "are",
    "start_offset" : 4,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "a",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "BADWORD",
    "start_offset" : 10,
    "end_offset" : 14,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 4
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Val. Allow me a chance to see how this solution can match my implementation. I don't necessarily want to implement word substitution, but to flag the document (in a classified site, someone might be giving away an "adorable pussy cat") which raises all kinds of flags.

Comment: Ok, I see, it is also possible to not substitue the badword but simply flag it with a synonym mapping like `word1 => word1, BADWORD`. Doing so will preserve the potential badword, but also add the `BADWORD` token just after it.